# R S4 class with Date attribute: error instantiating

Tags: r, date, initialization, instantiation, r-s4

I am constructing a S4 class in R that has some attributes of type "Date".
This is causing a problem within the validObject method which is fired when I am instantiating the Object.

```
setClass ("oblig", slots = c(name="character",issue_date="Date"))

myoblig<-new("oblig", name="TestOblig")
```

This returns the following error:

> Error in validObject(.Object) : 
>     invalid class “oblig” object: invalid object for slot "issue_date" in class "oblig": got class "S4", should be or extend class "Date"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue has to do with the fact that there is no "default" representation of a `Date` class object. Consider this:

```
R> as.integer()
#integer(0)
R> as.character()
#character(0)
R> as.numeric()
#numeric(0)
R> as.Date()
#Error in as.Date.default() : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

The "basic" types (for lack of better word) can be constructed out of nothing, but this is not the case with `Date` objects. In contrast, if we have the following class, `foo`, whose slots consist only of "basic" data types, partial initialization is not a problem:

```
foo <- setClass("foo", slots = c(s1 = "character", s2 = "numeric"))
bar <- new("foo", s1 = "abz")
##
R> bar
#An object of class "foo"
#Slot "s1":
#  [1] "abz"

#Slot "s2":
#  numeric(0)
```

---

That being said, I can think of three options using your `oblig` class:

```
oblig <- setClass(
  "oblig", 
  slots = c(name="character",issue_date="Date"))
```

---

First, you could just *instantiate* an `oblig`, i.e. don't initialize any of its slots. I'm completely sure about the specifics, but more or less I think the problem is that when you pass *any* additional values to `new`, it will cause the generic `initialize` function to be called, which will try to initialize all slots of the object.

For example,

```
no_init <- new("oblig")
##
R> no_init
#An object of class "oblig"
#Slot "name":
#  character(0)

#Slot "issue_date":
#  <S4 Type Object>
#  attr(,".S3Class")
#[1] "Date"
```

Then, you could just provide the slot value(s) afterwards:

```
no_init@issue_date <- Sys.Date()
##
R> no_init
#An object of class "oblig"
#Slot "name":
#  character(0)

#Slot "issue_date":
#  [1] "2015-08-21"
```

---

Second, you could provide a full initialization instead of a partial initialization:

```
full_init <- new("oblig", name = "TestOblig", issue_date = Sys.Date())
##
R> full_init
#An object of class "oblig"
#Slot "name":
#  [1] "TestOblig"

#Slot "issue_date":
#  [1] "2015-08-21"
```

No issues there.

---

Finally, you can specify the default initialization values by passing a list to the `prototype` argument of `setClass`:

```
oblig <- setClass(
  "oblig", 
  slots = c(name="character",issue_date="Date"),
  prototype = list(
    name = character(0), 
    issue_date = Sys.Date()))
##
partial_init <- new("oblig", name = "TestOblig")
##
R> partial_init
#An object of class "oblig"
#Slot "name":
#  [1] "TestOblig"

#Slot "issue_date":
#  [1] "2015-08-21"
```

Personally, I would take this route.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Clearly, the third proposition is the only way to go, as partial initialization is a must.